# Zf2 Pagination fetches all records

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, pagination, zend-framework2, zend-paginator

I had implemented the zf2 paginator. But now as the data increased I realized it is fetching all records first and then the pagination takes place, which takes more time. I did not realize the speed issue until the records went more than 1k.

**Does the paginator really works like this, or I am missing something in my code ?**

```
$photos = $em->getRepository('User\Entity\MyEntity')->findBy(array('id' => $main_id, 'status' => '1', 'is_primary' => '1'));

/** Create Paginator * */
$paginator = new \Zend\Paginator\Paginator(new
                \Zend\Paginator\Adapter\ArrayAdapter($photos)
             );

if (isset($data['pg_id'])) {
      $paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($data['pg_id']);
} else {
      $paginator->setCurrentPageNumber(1);
}
$paginator->setDefaultItemCountPerPage(25);
```

Comment: I'm not too familiar with doctrine (or whatever orm you're using), but doesn't the first line fetch a lot of data? I've actually found myself using [`NullFill`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.paginator.usage.html) adapter (I think it was called just `null` adapter before). It doesn't need the actual data, only total count of items (and a count query on an indexed field is faster than fetching all data).

Comment: Did you try to use [Doctrine paginator adapter](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/blob/master/docs/paginator.md) instead of the ArrayAdapter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @foozy alluded to in the comments, Doctrine provides paginator adapters for ZF2 for this purpose.  You can use [the Selectable adapter from `DoctrineModule`](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/blob/master/docs/paginator.md) directly or [the `DoctrinePaginator` class from `DoctrineORMModule`](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineORMModule/blob/master/src/DoctrineORMModule/Paginator/Adapter/DoctrinePaginator.php).  The latter doesn't have it's own documentation but [this blog post from Loft Digital explains it well](http://blog.loftdigital.com/blog/doctrine-plus-zf2-tips-pagination):

```
use DoctrineORMModule\Paginator\Adapter\DoctrinePaginator as DoctrineAdapter;
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination\Paginator as ORMPaginator;
use Zend\Paginator\Paginator;

// .......

$entityManager = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default');
$repository = $entityManager->getRepository('Admin\Entity\SystemUser');
$adapter = new DoctrineAdapter(new ORMPaginator($repository->createQueryBuilder('user')));
$paginator = new Paginator($adapter);

// .......
```

Comment: In that example it's passed into the constructor of ORMPaginator.  It expects a Doctrine query, in this case constructed using Query Builder (http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html)